# How to share a structure variable in multiple c files

Tags: c, struct

Let suppose I have a one structure

```
 struct A
 {
 int x;
 int y;
 }s;
```

Now suppose I want to share this structure variable i.e. 's' in multiple c files. How can I achieve this thing.

Should I use extern or I have to use the header file and include that header file in each c file

Comment: extern would work for you.

Comment: Well all the source files must know about the actual structure, which makes a header file useful.

Answer (score 3):

Split into header and code file.
Then include the header in each code file which needs to access the variable.
(Global variables should be used with care by the way.)

Header:

```
 struct A
 {
 int x;
 int y;
 };

extern A s;
```

A single code file:

```
#include "theheader.h"
A s;
```

Other code files:

```
#include "theheader.h"
/* access the variable */
```